# Passing a simple variable value for use in another class in Android

Tags: android

What is the correct way to pass a simple variable which has its value set to use in another class? I have a counter which is incremented with a button press and when counter = 3 a method is called which loads another activity which loads another screen with a string which states the button was pressed. Here is where I want to include the number 3 passed from the counter variable in the previous class, but I am not sure the correct way to do this. 
I tried creating an instance of the class and connecting to the variable that way but the value is never passed and it is always 0.

Comment: Not the same question, but the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308026/listview-onitemclicklistener-with-a-new-activity/9308067#9308067

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try following code,

```
public class First
{
   private static int myVarible = 0;


    private void myMethod()
    {
         myVariable = 5; // Assigning a value;
    }

    public static int getVariable()
    {
        return myVariable;
    }
}

public class Second
{
    int i = First.getVariable();  // Accessing in Another class
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! I knew it would be simple, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

You may pass value via Intent - resource bundle.

Pass value from current activity,

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("no",10);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in ResultActivity (onCreate),

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
int value=bundle.getInt("no");
```

In case of non-activity classes, you may define a public method.

For instance,

```
public Integer getValue() //returns a value
{
  return 10;
}
```

Or

```
public void setValue(Integer value)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it would be when you build your new intent to do :

```
Intent itn = new Intent(...,...);
itn.putExtra(KEY,VALUE);
startctivity(itn);
```

And on the other class do something like :

```
this.getIntent.getStringExtra(KEY);
or
this.getIntent.getWHATEVERYOURVARIABLEWASExtra(KEY);
```

Hope it helps you, and it's the better way to pass arguments between 2 activities :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it through define variable as "static" in one activity and in second activity use that variable with using `<<classname>>.<<variableb>>`

**ex:**

**Activity1:**

Static var = 5;

**Activity2:**

System.out.println(Activity1.var);

Answer (score 1):

You can pass that value using the intent

```
Intent new_intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("counter",10); //here the value is integer so you use the  new_intent.putExtra(String name,int value)
startActivity(new_intent);
```

After that in the second activity class you can get that that values using Bundle

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int count = bundle.getInt("counter");
```

I think this may help you.